# AutoFixture AutoMoq - SetReturnsDefault() does not work with fixture created mocks

Tags: mocking, moq, autofixture, automoq

I have a mock. This mock has two methods, **MethodA()** and **MethodB()**. I want to setup both methods to return **false**. I created various versions of the code, all of them should work, but some don't:

These work:

1.

```
var mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<MyInterface>>();
mock
    .Setup(m => m.MethodA(It.IsAny<T>(), It.IsAny<T>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(false);
mock
    .Setup(m => m.MethodB(It.IsAny<T>(), It.IsAny<T>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(false);

var sut = fixture.Create<MySut>();
sut.Do(); // Calls MethodA() and MethodB() - Both return false, works
```

2.

```
var mock = new Mock<MyInterface>();
mock.SetReturnsDefault(Task.FromResult(false));
fixture.Inject(mock);

var sut = fixture.Create<MySut>();
sut.Do(); // Calls MethodA() and MethodB() - Both return false, works
```

3.

```
var mock = new Mock<MyInterface>();
mock.SetReturnsDefault(Task.FromResult(false));
fixture.Inject(mock.Object);

var sut = fixture.Create<MySut>();
sut.Do(); // Calls MethodA() and MethodB() - Both return false, works
```

These don't:

4.

```
var mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<MyInterface>>();
mock.SetReturnsDefault(Task.FromResult(false));

var sut = fixture.Create<MySut>();
sut.Do(); // Calls MethodA() and MethodB() - MethodA returns true, fails
```

5.

```
var mock = fixture.Create<Mock<MyInterface>>();
mock.SetReturnsDefault(Task.FromResult(false));
fixture.Inject(mock);

var sut = fixture.Create<MySut>();
sut.Do(); // Calls MethodA() and MethodB() - MethodA returns true, fails
```

6.

```
var mock = fixture.Create<Mock<MyInterface>>();
mock.SetReturnsDefault(Task.FromResult(false));
fixture.Inject(mock.Object);

var sut = fixture.Create<MySut>();
sut.Do(); // Calls MethodA() and MethodB() - MethodA returns true, fails
```

Based on results, it seems the culprit is the **Fixture.Create()** method*. For some reason, if the mock is created using **fixture.Create()** instead of **new** keyword, it will not keep the configuration I set up using **SetReturnsDefault()**, even if the mock is frozen (meaning **Fixture.Inject()** was called on it). Can someone explain why?

---

*Footnote:*

* **Fixture.Create()** is also called internally when you call **Fixture.Freeze()** - Freeze is just a shorthand for a call to **Fixture.Create()** followed by **Fixture.Inject()**

Therefore, these two snippets are equivalent:

```
var mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<MyInterface>>();
```

-

```
var mock = fixture.Create<Mock<MyInterface>>();
fixture.Inject(mock);
```

Comment: Are you creating the SUT after the mock is Frozen/Injected ?

Comment: Have you included the `AutoMoqCustomization` on the fixture, or is `Fixture.Create` being used by itself, sans the automoqcustomization?  Customizations will affect what `fixture.Create` does behind the scenes.

Comment: @JeffDammeyer yes I included AutoMoqCustomization but nothing special inside, just configure members = true; This should not affect objects created by mocks afaik, only  objects created by fixture.

Comment: @JeffDammeyer I tried couple of things based on your comment and I found some curious behavior. If I create my fixture as a test input parameter like this: MyTest(Fixture fixture), the code does not work as I described above. If I create fixture object in the code of the test, however: var fixture = new Fixture();, everything suddenly works. In both cases I have the customization enabled. If I set ConfigureMembers= false; in the customization, the input parameter version starts working too. Soo, wow. This does not make any sense to me, any idea why is it behaving this way?...

Comment: My mock setup should override the behavior of the mock regardless of where I create the fixture object, right?

Comment: @Andrew yes the sut is created afterwards, but just to make sure, I just created version of code where I call the mock directly without any sut after I set it up. I did this: 1. create mock 2. setup mock 3. call mock.MethodA() and mock.MethodB().  And it still ignores the SetReturnsDefault() I give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you shared that you're using the `AutoMoqCustomization`, it explains the behavior you see, though it's due to some internals in both `Moq` and `AutoFixture` interacting in a way you may not expect.

For completeness sake, here's a stubbed out version of the class and interface you mentioned in your question:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface
{
    Task<bool> MethodA();

    Task<bool> MethodB();
}

public class Sut
{
    private readonly IMyInterface dep;

    public Sut(IMyInterface dep)
    {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Do()
    {
        var one = await dep.MethodA();
        var two = await dep.MethodB();

        return one || two;
    }
}
```

And here's a test we can use to illustrate the interaction of the two behaviors:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task FixtureNoConfigureMembers()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = false });

    var mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IMyInterface>>();

    mock.SetReturnsDefault(Task.FromResult(false));

    var sut = fixture.Create<Sut>();
    var result = await sut.Do();
    Assert.False(result);
}
```

The two salient implementation details to consider are:

- What AutoFixture does when you specify `ConfigureMembers = true` in the customization.
- How Moq determines when to use the default value set by `SetReturnsDefault`

As both projects are open source, it's simple enough to peek under the covers. I won't paste each individual class here, but you can check [Autofixture's source](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/tree/master/Src/AutoMoq) and [Moq's source](https://github.com/moq/moq4/tree/master/src/Moq) if you desire more detail.

Moq's `SetReturnsDefault` has fairly straightforward behavior:

- If a setup matches, that setup is used. The default return value is ignored. This is the important bit.
- If no setup matches, and the return value is of the correct type, that default value is returned.

On the autofixture side...

`AutoMoqCustomization` makes it so that, when a specimen of type `Mock<T>` is requested, AutoFixture will first create the Mock by essentially calling `new Mock<T>()` (It's slightly more nuanced than that, but it's essentially the case for this interface.)

After creating the mock, if `ConfigureMembers` is true, Autofixture will *additionally* enumerate all the virtual methods of the mocked type, and do the equivalent of

```cs
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodName(It.IsAny<T>... for all arguments... ))
    .Returns(fixture.Create<TReturn>())
```

This overrides the default behavior of the `AutoMoqCustomization`, which is to allow Moq to handle the default value selection (usually by having it create its own mocks).

You can probably see where this is headed. Because AutoFixture has created setups for all of the virtual methods, this completely overrides the `SetReturnsDefault` behavior provided by Moq.

Note that this behavior is because Moq didn't used to have the `SetReturnsDefault` method-- so AutoFixture couldn't utilize the DefaultValueProvider in order to inject specimens that it creates. There's a [PR on AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/pull/1145) to change the behavior to utilize the `DefaultValueProvider` property provided by Moq. Presumably that would restore the ability for `SetReturnsDefault` to override the behavior for a particular type. (Though I haven't explored the PR in any depth at all)

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. I actually thought AutoFixture only used Moq to create objects from interfaces it could not instantiate itself. It never occurred to me that it was also setting up return values of those mocked objects.